# How to create an Azure DevOps Pipeline via RestAPI and enable

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-rest-api

My project's code is on Github, and the CI/CD pipelines are defined in Azure DevOps.
The idea is that when a new PR happens, it triggers the CI pipeline in Azure.

I've automated the creations of pipelines, using the Azure RestAPI, for that we are using: /_apis/pipelines version 7.1. I did it using [this reference](https://johnnyreilly.com/create-pipeline-with-azure-devops-api).

When registering it automatically through the API, the PRs are not triggering the CI pipeline; after some investigation, I found out that the trigger for PRs is, by default, disabled. As can be seen in the picture below.

Do you know any way to modify it via API, either by default enabling it or changing it after it's created?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `Override the YAML the PR trigger` and `Enable pull request validation` of a GitHub repo with this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2#definitiontriggertype).

Per the request body of above request, you may first get the **latest** pipeline definition revision from the response of the following [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2) first.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}?api-version=7.2-preview.7
```

We can then copy the response as the body of the `Definition-Update-API` request and simply update the `triggerS` section. Here is a sample json contents of the modified `trigger` section for your reference. In the second object for `"triggerType":  "pullRequest"`, I removed `"settingsSourceType":  2,` and updated `"branchFilters":  ["+refs/heads/main"]`.

```
PUT https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}?api-version=7.2-preview.7

{
    …
    "triggers":  [
                         {
                             "branchFilters":  "",
                             "pathFilters":  "",
                             "settingsSourceType":  2,
                             "batchChanges":  false,
                             "maxConcurrentBuildsPerBranch":  1,
                             "triggerType":  "continuousIntegration"
                         },
                         {
    
                             "branchFilters":  [
                                "+refs/heads/main"
                             ],
                             "forks":  "@{enabled=False; allowSecrets=False; allowFullAccessToken=False}",
                             "pathFilters":  "",
                             "requireCommentsForNonTeamMembersOnly":  false,
                             "requireCommentsForNonTeamMemberAndNonContributors":  false,
                             "isCommentRequiredForPullRequest":  false,
                             "pipelineTriggerSettings":  "@{forkProtectionEnabled=True; buildsEnabledForForks=True; enforceJobAuthScopeForForks=False; enforceNoAccessToSecretsFromForks=False; isCommentRequiredForPullRequest=False; requireCommentsForNonTeamMembersOnly=False; requireCommentsForNonTeamMemberAndNonContributors=False}",
                             "triggerType":  "pullRequest"
                         }
                     ],
    …
}
```